# Transparent background in grouped UITableView - iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, background, transparency

I want to make the grouped UITableView transparent. I partially succeded with the following code:

```
UIColor *bgColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithWhite:1 alpha:0.0];
historyTable.backgroundColor = bgColor;
```

Unfortunately, black corners appeared in the rounded cells. How to get rid of them?

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Instead of using

```
UIColor *bgColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithWhite:1 alpha:0.0];
historyTable.backgroundColor = bgColor;
```

Just use:

```
historyTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

That also clears up the memory leak you were creating.

Comment: Thank you very much. BTW I relese bgColor later on, but thanks for your concern ;).

Comment: nice one.. just what i needed today

Comment: Note: [UIColor clearColor] must currently be set in code, it doesn't work if the clearColor is set in Interface Builder.

Comment: Didn't know that; I never use IB. It might be worth submitting a bug report if this is the case.

Comment: Yeah, try using a color with a certain alpha value above zero. That said, however, I'm not sure how'd you deal with the black corners (if they appear).

Comment: By the way, `[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0]` also works, as that is what `[UIColor clearColor]` is really equal to. Due to some oversight, colors with alpha 0 but different RGB values are not equal.

Answer (score 35):

remove UITableView backgroundView

```
xxx.backgroundView = nil;
```

This is necessary on iPad builds. When compiling to run on iPad and iPhone, check the tableView responds to the selector with ...

```
if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundView:)]) {
    [self.tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
}
```

Comment: setBackgroundView: available from iOS 3.2 and not pinned to iPad, isn't it? Why one should use this check?

Answer (score 8):

for me it worked finaly after setting both to nil/clear:

```
[myTableView setBackgroundView:nil];
[myTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: No need to set the background color to clear after setting the background view to nil.

Comment: in my case i had to do it or i end up with a white background. but thats maybe a special case.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue and found that there was no difference between using:

```
[[UIColor alloc] initWithWhite:1 alpha:0.0];
```

and using:

```
[UIColor clearColor];
```

I tried both of these and still had the little black corners on my table view.

I also tried setting the backgroundView to nil as suggested, but this didn't work either.

I solved this by setting the backgrounds of the individual cells to transparent in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
cell.backgroundColor =  [UIColor clearColor];
```

Of course, this has the side effect that your cells themselves are transparent, which isn't ideal for everyone, but it ok for me in this case.