# How i hide the header and footer of UITableView Controller?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I develop an application in which i selected the UITableView (only two row) having group style on the UIViewController with background image. But i want to be only those two row of the group table shold be displayed on the background image, and the header and footer of the table must be hide.
How i do that? 
[alt text http://file:///Users/Nikhilesh/Desktop/image.png](http://file:///Users/Nikhilesh/Desktop/image.png)

Comment: can you attach an snapshot please?

Comment: @medopal, yes i have attached an example of table that i want
 but i confuse it will display or not.

Comment: I don't see an image.  Are you trying to hide the section header/footer or the table header/footer?

Comment: @progrmr, yah i want to hide the header and footer section on table.

Comment: when i trying to attaching the image, in question instead of image the text has been displayed.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is to make the background of the tableview transparent so that your image is visible behind the table?  Is that it?

Comment: @progrmr, yes that i want to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT2** - OK, now I think that what you really want is to make the background of the table view transparent so that your background image is visible.  This is [answered in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396250/transparent-background-in-grouped-uitableview-iphone) on SO, give that answer a try.  These questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894875/how-can-i-set-the-background-of-uitableview-the-tableview-style-is-grouped-to-u) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898351/iphone-setting-background-on-uitableview/2459591#2459591) explain how to use your own image for the background of the table view.

Comment: @progrmr, i trying also those method but it doesn't help me.

Comment: Is there some text displayed in your header?  Or it is taking up space and you want to remove the space?

Comment: @progrmr thanks for sending.
But i want to display only white cell not the gray background color.
That color i want to clear because it hides my background image.

Comment: how u attaching the image in answer?

Comment: @Rajendra: See EDIT2 part above about transparent UITableView backgrounds.