# Dark Corners UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController. In viewDidLoad, I do the following:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_cafe.png"]];
```

The background is supposed to be a gradient. Two issues:

1. Gradient seems to get cut off at the end of the UITableView.
2. The corners are tinted.

I've experimented with setting the UITableCell's opacity to NO, but that doesn't worked. I have read these threads already: [Transparent background in grouped UITableView - iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396250/transparent-background-in-grouped-uitableview-iphone), and [Black corners around UITableViewCells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527587/black-corners-around-uitableviewcells).

I'm not using Interface Builder at all for this.

Example:

[image: Example of tinted corners]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a UIView with that pattern image as background color and set it as table view's background view.

```
UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];
bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_cafe.png"]];
self.tableView.backgroundView = bgView;
[bgView release];
```

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to work. Can you give the rationale behind doing this vs. what I was doing?

Comment: I'd like to say you did something wrong :) but it's Apple's engineers that did something wrong. I have submitted countless bug reports about UITableView and UITableViewCell regarding semi-transparent and transparent backgrounds. I had the same problem as you on one of my projects and found this solution by experimenting.